# Didn't display any option in dropdown ( autocomplete component) using cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I'm doing a test of an autocomplete component.

The problem is when I want to select an option from the dropdown, it shows me any option. When I did the test manually there are options but with cypress no. It worked and after no. I couldn't see the problem.

Does anyone know how to do it please? 
(In cypress it didn't show any error)

Here the code of the autocomplete in js file

```
<Autocomplete
    id={"name-label-" + label.customId}
    options={options}
    getOptionLabel={option => (option && option.name) ? option.name:''}

    noOptionsText="No options"
    renderInput={params => (
         <TextField {...params} label="Select the name" fullWidth />

        )}
    data-cy="fichaSelectname"
    onChange={(event, value) => handleOptionChange(event, value)}
    value={option}
    classes={classesAutocomplete}

 />
```

And here's the cypress code I used

```
cy.get('[data-cy=fichaSelectname]').click().type('{downarrow}').type('{enter}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by selecting one element instead of just using the arrow buttons?

```
cy.get('[data-cy=fichaSelectname]').type('value{downarrow}{enter}');
```

Comment: please dont ask a question while you answering.
if your answer contains question please write in a comment

Comment: It looks more like a possible answer than a question to me. I don't see the problem.

Comment: no I didn' try it but the problem I want to select one element from the list but when displaying the list there are nothing no options to select. This is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Cypress did now show any stacktrace/error/info at all?

Well, first of all your code is wrong:

[cy.get](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Selector) should be used like that: `cy.get('[data-cy="fichaSelectname"]')`

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No did not show any error at all the test is running correct.
I tried with your code and same thing nothing changed.